# tf.parse_example used in mnist export example

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am new to tensorflow and are reading mnist_export.py in tensorflow serving example.

There is something here I cannot understand:

```
  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example')
  feature_configs = {
      'x': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[784], dtype=tf.float32),
  }
  tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)
  x = tf.identity(tf_example['x'], name='x')  # use tf.identity() to assign name
```

Above, serialized_tf_example is a Tensor.

I have read the api document [tf.parse_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/converting#parse_example) but it seems that `serialized` is serialized `Example` protos like:

```
serialized = [
  features
    { feature { key: "ft" value { float_list { value: [1.0, 2.0] } } } },
  features
    { feature []},
  features
    { feature { key: "ft" value { float_list { value: [3.0] } } }
]
```

So how to understand `tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)` here as `serialized_tf_example` is a Tensor, not `Example` proto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `serialized_tf_example` is serialized string of a `tf.train.Example`. See [tf.parse_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/converting#parse_example) for the usage. [Reading data](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/#file_formats) chapter gives some example link.

tf_example.SerializeToString() converts `tf.train.Example` to string and tf.parse_example parses the serialized string to a dict.

Answer (score 3):

The below mentioned code provides the simple example of using parse_example

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[1], name='serialized_tf_example')
feature_configs = {'x': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32)}
tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)

feature_dict = {'x': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[25]))}
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
f = example.SerializeToString()


sess.run(tf_example,feed_dict={serialized_tf_example:[f]})
```